# Is there a limit to how many times the scanf function can be used?

Tags: c, io, scanf

In an effort to get back into the flow of C programming, I've been typing up some simple test programs. I've ran into a strange problem with the scanf function. I have 3 in the following code, but only the first 2 are initialized; the third scanf is ignored. Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong? I've been staring at this code for the last half an hour and I can't find any errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int math(int a, int b, char selection) {

    int result;

    switch (selection) {
        case 'a':
        result = a + b;
        break;
        case 's':
        result = a - b;
        break;
        case 'm':
        result = a * b;
        break;
        case 'd':
        result = a / b;
        break;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int result = 0;
    char selection;

    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%i", &num1);

    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%i", &num2);

    printf("\n[a] Add\n[s] Subtract\n[m] Multiply\n[d] Divide\n\nWhich one: ");
    scanf("%c", &selection);

    result = math(num1, num2, selection);
    printf("%i", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The scanf isn't ignored, it's consuming a leftover newline character.

Comment: For getting character-by-character input, use `fgetc()` or `getc()`. For getting line-by-line user input, use `fgets()`. For reading from a binary file, use `fread()` (or `read()` from the POSIX C library, if necessary/available).

Comment: @JanD - If you see many of his answers, @H2CO3 is biased against the use of `scanf()` because of the hidden nuances of this function that trip everyone up. I don’t argue that it can be tricky, but using the documentation and good debugging skills and its really not such a bad little function

Comment: @Mike well, except for its consistent tendency to cause buffer overruns, you mean?

Comment: @JanD - again, that's just in the case you don't use a limiter. To H2CO3's comment: `scanf("%9s", now_were_ok_if_our_buffer_is_10);`. Limiting your input and using correct input types and the return codes, etc is all in the man pages or the C spec

Comment: @Mike yeah. And you then change the buffer size to 5, and you forget to update the hard-coded size. Happens all the time. Why bother, when you could as well just use `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)`?

Comment: Note: With `scanf("%i"`, entering values like "013" will result in a `int` value of `11` as leading zeros imply octal.  With `scanf("%d"`, the input string is only view as decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your over all question:

*Is there a limit to how many times the scanf function can be used?*

**No, no there is not.**

but that's not what is happening here anyway.

When you do something like this:

```
printf("Enter second number: ");
scanf("%i", &num2);
```

You're actually entering two values on `stdin`, first a number, second an invisible newline character.

```
                     you can't see that, but it's there
                         V
> Enter second number: 3\n
```

The way [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) works, it will read and store input from `stdin` to your variables until they are all filled, then it will leave the rest. In my example `3` got stored to `num2` and `'\n'` is left on `stdin` Then when this code runs:

```
scanf("%c", &selection);
```

It will look on `stdin` and find the newline character (`'\n'`) sitting there. This can be stored to a character type, so it will fill `selection` with it.

One way to fix this is to change your code to:

```
scanf(" %c", &selection);
```

The space before the `%` tells `scanf` to ignore any white space (including newlines) that are at the start of the `stdin` buffer.

---

Side note on debugging:

When you think something is going wrong, either use a debugger or print some values to give you confidence and understanding. For example, I would update your code as such:

```
printf("\n[a] Add\n[s] Subtract\n[m] Multiply\n[d] Divide\n\nWhich one: ");
int ret = scanf("%c", &selection);

printf("Scanf I think failed. Return value is: %d. Selection is: %c (%d)\n", 
        ret, selection, selection);
```

You can find the meaning of return values from man pages. In [this case](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) the return code here will tell you how many items were successfully matched and assigned. You'd see 1 here, so you know the call worked. Your output would look like:

```
Scanf I think failed. Return value is: 1. Selection is:
(10)
```

This tells you that `scanf` did indeed get *something*, you don't see a character printed, but the output skipped a line (suspicious) and the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of what was printed was 10<sub>10</sub>, looking that up you'll see it's a newline character.

Comment: I would have never figured that out. Thank you.

Comment: Minor: Suggest the parens around `%c` instead:  `"Selection is:(%c) %d"`.